# I don't know what hash (#) means in zsh

Tags: zsh

curl is a command that I use quite often on command line. When I'm using ZSH, I found that the -# option does not work; that option works fine in BASH -- see code below:

```
ZSH:
→ curl --progress-bar www.google.com  > google.html
######################################################################## 100.0%

→ curl -# www.google.com  > google.html
zsh: no matches found: -#

BASH:
$ curl --progress-bar www.google.com  > google.html
######################################################################## 100.0%

$ curl -# www.google.com  > google.html
######################################################################## 100.0%
```

Of course, I can define an alias to work around this problem if I don't want to type the full option name (that is, --progress-bar). But I'm just curious as to what part of ZSH is controlling this behavior and whether any way to customize/redefine this behavior in any my .zshrc file.  Many thanks in advance for any useful information!

Comment: Quotes. `'-#'` will moot any kind of shell-local behavior.

Answer (score 5):

In `zsh`, if `.zshrc` has the below line which is causing this problem for `curl`

```
setopt extended_glob
```

this option means

> "Treat the #, ~ and ^ characters as part of patterns for filename generation, etc. (An initial unquoted ~ always produces named directory expansion.)"

so I think it should better to use `--progress-bar` instead of `-#` (or) including it in quotes should preserve the characters as it is, not causing the shell to expand it.

found this in [curl progress-bar option in GitHub](https://github.com/creationix/nvm/issues/28).

Comment: Thanks! quoting '-#' works fine! And for the relevant information!

Comment: @charlesqwu: You could click on the small tick on the left of my answer to mark it accepted, for making it useful for future reference.

Comment: In addition, the problem is that by default `zsh` treats a pattern that doesn't match anything as an error, rather than treating it as a literal string as `bash` does. Using `setopt nonomatch` will change that.

Comment: although the OP asked for no aliases, it seems reasonable to mention noglob, this prevents such expansions as well as not having to enclose quotes around the ~# parm:  alias curl='noglob curl'